# Powershell the local farm is not accessible - SPECIAL NUANCE

Tags: powershell

Wonder if you could shed some light on a variant of this situation I'm experiencing.

Typical Error when running Sharepoint Management Shell
"the local farm is not accessible. CmdLets...."

Here's the scenario:

POC situation.  2 servers

web front-end (sharepoint 2010 fully updated installed here)

db / app server (sharepoint 2010 fully updated installed here, as well as sql 2012 fully updated)

Username Joe is local admin on both boxes, sysadmin on the sql server and has shell-admin role applied. Username Joe can on web front-end, but ***cannot*** use sharepoint management shell on db / app server.

Powershell version is 2.0 on both boxes - double-checked -version 2 is added in the short-cut

Tried import system modules (get the same error)

Tried Run-as-administrator (get the same error)

double-checked local administrators membership

double-checked UAC off

ExecutionPolicy is the same on both boxes.

db server role is "sysadmin".

db-shell-admin role has been applied and removed and applied and removed ... using Add/Remove-SPShellAdmin (incidentally - regardless of this setting, the web front-end has no issues with powershell administration - pressumably since user Joe is a sysadmin).

Anything I've missed?

Comment: Confirm Joe is a Farm Admin in SP?

Comment: confirm Joe also has rights on the Config DB? also logoff the Joe from the server having issue and login again, or may be restart the server.

Comment: Confirmed Joe is part of Farm Administrators Group.  What "rights" on the ConfigDB, specifically?  Joe's a sysadmin on the db-server (I've explicitly tested db_owner as well).  Both servers have been rebooted multiple times.  Joe is not running through a temporary profile either.  Joe has been added to ShellAdmin role and tested (yes on web no on app) and then removed from ShellAdmin role and tested (yes on web no on app)

Comment: Joe should be do on config db. Did you try to run power shell with farm admin account, the account running timer services? Are you using sharepoint power shell or windows powershell?

Comment: I'm using Sharepoint Powershell - Joe Can be the farm account too - doesn't seem to matter which one i use.

Comment: I cheated (well - couldn't figure it out so found a work-around) - went to the server, started the configuration wizard and disconnected from farm.  rebooted, rejoined the farm and everything is fine.